# PHP SoapClient Long Request Strings Throw "Bad Request" Exception

Tags: php, soap-client

So I use PHP's SoapClient to import order data via a web service. We have PHP 5.2 installed on a Windows Server 2008, and the web service itself is in a .NET environment.

For almost any order, everything works fine, however very large orders might have so many order items that the request string that we send is quite long. In these cases, the request fails, with very little helpful information.

- The faultcode is `"HTTP"`
- The faultstring is `"Bad Request"`
- The faultmessage is `null`.
- The `__getLastResponse()` is null.

It's probably due to a PHP setting, rather than a bug in SoapClient.

Comment: You have to enable tracing when you instantiate SoapClient for the debug functions to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mike. I actually do have tracing enabled, and have used __getLastResponse() successfully in other situations. I think it returns null, because it's not even attempting to send the request.

Comment: One interesting thing I've discovered: The content length in the request headers is 68597, but the actual length should only be 21148. Why would the content length in the header be so much longer?